Magnitude of current in transformers
In an ideal transformer, can the magnitude of current in the secondary coil be found without the power formula but by using the fact that $V = L \ \mathrm{d}i/\mathrm{d}t$? I tried this but ended up getting current in the secondary equal to the current in the primary, which is not generally true.

You can use the equivalent magnetic circuit, using an engineering approximation.
The magnetic flux created by coil 1 with $N_1$ windings and current $i_1$ is
$$\Phi_1 = A_1 b_1 = \mu \frac{A_1 N_1}{\ell_1} i_1$$
while
$$v_1 = \dfrac{\mathrm{d} \Psi_1}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\mathrm{d} (N_1 \Phi_1)}{\mathrm{d}t} = N_1 \dot{\Phi}_1 \ = \mu \dfrac{A_1 N^2_1}{\ell_1} \dfrac{\mathrm{d} i_1}{dt} = L_1 \frac{\mathrm{d} i_1}{\mathrm{d}t} \ ,$$
for constant geometry.
In an ideal transformer, the magnetic flux $\Phi$ is constant in all sections of the ferromagnetic material, so that at coil 2
$$\Phi_2 = \Phi_1 \ .$$
$$\frac{v_1}{N_1} = \frac{v_2}{N_2} \ ,$$
and for electric current
$$\mu \frac{A_1 N_1^2}{\ell_1 N_1} \frac{\mathrm{d} i_1}{\mathrm{d}t} = \mu \frac{A_2 N_2^2}{\ell_2 N_2} \frac{\mathrm{d} i_2}{\mathrm{d}t} \qquad \rightarrow \qquad \frac{A_1 N_1}{\ell_1}\dfrac{\mathrm{d} i_1}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{A_2 N_2}{\ell_2}\dfrac{\mathrm{d} i_2}{\mathrm{d}t}.$$
